# Fazer o mouse agir com um joystick

Tags: java, eventos-do-mouse, java-processing

O meu código deve fazer o mouse agir com um joystick para dirigir uma bola na tela. Ele deve funcionar da seguinte forma: se o mouse estiver na mira, a bola não se move. Se o mouse é para a direita ou para a esquerda, a bola move-se para a direita ou para a esquerda. Se o mouse estiver acima ou abaixo do centro, a bola se move para cima ou para baixo. A distância do mouse do centro determina a rapidez com que a bola se move.
Eu consegui implementar o código para desenhar a bola e a mira. Mas não consigo fazer a bola se mover corretamente. Como eu uso min e max funções nesse caso?

```
int ballPositionX = 250;
int ballPositionY = 250;
int ballSize = 20;
int slowerSpeed = 50;
int mouvement = 250;
int linePt1 = 100;
int linePt2 = 250; 
int linePt3 = 400;
int rightLimit, leftLimit, bottomLimit, topLimit;

int moveX, moveY;

void setup(){
  size(500,500);
}

void draw(){
  background(255);
  line(linePt1,linePt2,linePt3,linePt2);
  line(linePt2,linePt1,linePt2,linePt3);
  ellipse(ballPositionX, ballPositionY, ballSize, ballSize);
  moveX = (mouseX - 250);
  moveY = (mouseY - 250);
  ballPositionX = min(ballPositionX, moveX+ballPositionY);
  ballPositionY = max(ballPositionY, moveY+ballPositionX);
}
```

Comment: Você vai precisar de um MouseAdapter (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseAdapter.html)

Comment: Não @prmottajr. Eu preciso calcular ballPositionX e ballPositionY. Eu sei que é coisa simples, mas to quebrando a cabeça aqui.

Comment: Adicione um **[mcve]**, pois como se trata de swing, é preciso testar o problema para obter resultados melhores para sugerir e seu código não é executável.

Comment: A linguagem Processing não usa swing pelo que eu sei. E mais mais simples que isso, mas nao sei resolver.

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger a solução inclui min e max. Sim, a fórmula está errada. E é isso que estou pedindo ajuda.

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger a soluçnao também não inclui IF. Por isso estou quebrando a cabeça.